# Can I deserialize json to anonymous type in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, json, .net-3.5

I read from the DB a long json.
I want just one attribute of that json.

I have got two options:
a. Create an interface for that json and deserialize to that interface. 
   (Is it an overkill as I need just one attribute ?)
b. Find the substring I need (regex? )

which one is preferred ?

**update: I'm using .net 3.5**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why don't you deserialize using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)'s "LINQ to JSON" approach (`JObject` etc) and just ask for the value you need by name?

That's sufficiently dynamic so you don't need to create an interface for *everything*, but it's a lot less brittle than using a regex.

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(text);
JToken value = json["foo"]["bar"];
```

(I believe JSON.NET also support's `dynamic` in .NET 4, but there's no particular need to use it here.)

Answer (score 18):

Regex must be absolutely out of any discussion. Just forget about it, it's as if it never existed.

Creating and working with strong types is a good thing and probably the way I would go.

But if you want, you could also use `dynamic`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{ 'foo': { 'bar': 'bar value', 'baz': [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic value = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine(value["foo"]["baz"][1]);
    }
}
```

prints `2` on the console.

Comment: I'm using c# 3.5 I don't think there is dynamic type. right ?

Comment: @Elad Benda, no there isn't. Well then you could use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) which offers a similar syntax.

Answer (score 2):

On .NET 4:

You can do something kind of like what you want minus the need for regex (and you shouldn't use regex for something like this!) by using the `dynamic` feature of C# 4.0 described here: http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

The only downside is that you can't guarantee what the exact structure of the object is.

The upswing is that instead of accessing members via `yourDynamicObject['blah']`, it's the more duck-type-ish `yourDynamicObject.blah`

On .NET 3.5:

You can use Json.NET: http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Finding the substring is a dangerous optimisation.

Is it worth optimising the process (compared to a JSON deserialization) and safe to do such a lookup ? We can't answer *yes* because it's mostly dependent on the context. But I feel like saying **NO** because it's obviously looking for trouble: Even if it works now, it may get broken in the future when the structure or contents of you object changes.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but here goes another method on .NET 3.5: you can cast the object returned by DeserializeObject to a Dictionary<String, Object>. It's kind of the same solution as using the .NET 4.0 dynamic keyword:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Object obj = serializer.DeserializeObject("{ 'name': 'vinicius fonseca', 'age': 31 }");
Dictionary<String, Object> ret = (Dictionary<String, Object>)obj;
Console.WriteLine(ret["name"].GetType().Name); // Output: String
Console.WriteLine(ret["name"].ToString()); // Output: vinicius fonseca
Console.WriteLine(ret["age"].GetType().Name); // Output: Int32
Console.WriteLine(ret["age"].ToString()); // Output: 31
```

Hope it helps someone.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new { Foo="", Bar=""});
```

This will return a dynamic object with the fields you defined.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Option A is the more strict, disciplined, and formal way.  Yet, again like you said it may be overkill.  How fat is that json?  Long term, Option A leaves the future potential possibility that you may need to use more than one property.

Option B is definitely more informal and straight forward.  It will definitely work today, but may require a different solution in the future.

Thus, maybe you would want to wrap the entire process in a method to hide the implementation from the calling client.  Return your custom object with only the lone property populated.  Then, if the need arises in the future you can change the method to utilize full tilt deserialization.

Note: I do not think deserialization to an anonymous type in C# 3.5 is possible.