# How to parse json response from yahoo sever?

Tags: c#, json, yahoo

I get address book from yahoo mail service.

```
"https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/" + xoauth_yahoo_guid + "/contacts?format=json"
```

The contacts I get in json format.

I want to parse it  to c# object ,using this row:

```
 new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Type>(contactsToParse);
```

The problem is that I can't create c# **Type** because I don't know the archeticture of json format that I get back from yahoo server.
I tryed to look in yahoo api documentation but I didnt find anything.
Any idea what is the archeticture of json response should be?

Comment: Only the Yahoo docs can help with this one unless you can decode the Json yourself!

Comment: You can deserialize into an anonymous type.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485962/can-i-deserialize-json-to-anonymous-type-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this link - https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html

After making request, note down data formats , and create a class or nested class structure depending on that structure , and use that class name in .